# is there a way to convert the ?: operator in a string to python conditional statment?

Tags: python

I am using python to parse a text file which contains the ternary operator **a ? b:c**

I would like to convert the ?: operator to python conditional statement **b if a else c**.

example:

```
expression = "(2.4**l2) + 8.0*( (l3>=l4) ? k2:k3 )"
converted_expression = "(2.4**l2) + 8.0*(k2 if (l3>=l4) else k3 )"
```

Comment: The expression you have in your example is a very *clean* one; plenty of spaces etc. Will that always be the case?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis no it could be anything :(

Comment: I'd locate the "?" token, and would extract the tokens (with an even number of open/close parens) to get the left & right tokens, then same thing for the rightmost token of `:`. Works if there aren't any nested "?" expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a regex? This particular regex doesn't care about spaces and is using named capture groups for clarity

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'\((?P<cond>.*)\) ?\? ?(?P<if_true>.+):(?P<if_false>.+)')

string = '(l3>=l4) ? k2:k3'
match = regex.search(string)
print('{if_true} if {cond} else {if_false}'.format(if_true=match.group('if_true'),
                                                   cond=match.group('cond'),
                                                   if_false=match.group('if_false')))

# k2 if l3>=l4 else k3
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is probably kind of limited, but you can go with the following:

```
converted_expression = "(2.4**l2) + 8.0*([k3,k2][bool(l3>=l4)])"
```

The **bool(...)** part will return **False** or **True** which is auto-converted into 0 and 1 respectively as a list index.

Comment: OP wants to create a string, not evaluate the expression.

Comment: @DeepSpace Oh. I thought the problem is a one-line python equivalent of ternar **(condition? if true: if false)** operator.